# ReactJS, Can't get Object values from API by ID passed in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS and JavaScript and I'm trying to pass ID through URL to "UserInfo.js", next I'm trying to get this ID in "GetUser.js" and by this ID ask API to show me informations (such as login, id, etc.) from DataBase. I have problem with React. API works fine in swaggerUI.

Code of GetUser.js:

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { stringify } from 'uuid';
import UserInfo from './UserInfo';


export class GetUser extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            id: null,
            userTable: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        var test = <UserInfo/>;
        this.state.id = test;
        this.GetUserById();
    }

    GetUserById(){
        let id;
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'User/'+{id},{
            method:'GET',
            header:{'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({userTable:data});
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(this.state.id)
    }
}
```

Code of UserInfo.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function UserInfo(){
    let { id } = useParams();

    return (id);
}
export default UserInfo;
```

Routing:

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import {LoginPage} from './LoginPage';
import {Home} from './Home';
import UserInfo from './UserInfo';
import {Users} from './Users';
import {AddUser} from './AddUser';
import {GetUser} from './GetUser';
import {Profile} from './Profile';

function Routers() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<LoginPage/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/Home' element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/Uzytkownicy' element={<Users/>}/>
            <Route path='/DodajUzytkownika' element={<AddUser/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/Uzytkownicy/:id" element={<GetUser/>} component={UserInfo}/>
            <Route path='/Profil' element={<Profile/>}/>
          </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Routers;
```

Only what I got from console is "[object Object]" or errors of Hooks
[Picture of errors in network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15n23.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the fetch:

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+`User/${id}`,{
            method:'GET',
            header:{'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'}
         })
```

Notice to " ` " around URL.

Tell me, did it help you?

Comment: Doesn't work, I use similar fetch to delete users and it works, but I think I can't get correct ID from URL to pass it into API

Comment: @MJayK I'm sorry. I was just suspicious of how the id was placed in the URL. I also have a problem with my project, that I want to get content from the server, by sending id through URL. contents not received. I self-used the same syntax that I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for writing it, but sadly cannot help in this case, still trying to fix my problem.

Answer (score -1):

In a React class component, you can access the parameters using `this.props.location.search`.

You can parse the result like so:

```
new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get("id")
```

I would not try to access React hooks (like `useParams`) in a class component. The purpose of hooks in React is to provide state and lifecycle methods to functional components, but class components already have these things.
You are creating a functional component (`UserInfo`) purely so that you can call a hook so that you can access state that your class component already has access to.